# How to define the stability (or convergence) of a ordering of a list of node

Tags: algorithms, graphs, sorting, ordering

I have a problem which requires ordering nodes in a graph based on some given statistics. However, the given statistics of each node may be very hard to compute. Thus, I will use some sampling techniques to compute approximate statistics for each node. With more samples, the approximate estimated statistics will be more close to the exact one.

However, I want to terminate the sampling process when the ordering of nodes based on the statistics is stable. In this problem, I do not need to know the exact statistics of each node. The right ordering of these nodes is what matters.

So, my question is that is there any metric to define the stability of a ordering? How can I make sure that the ordering converges such that the ordering will not be changed notably?

Comment: Would it be correct to say you assign each node a [confidence interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval) which becomes smaller and smaller the longer you run your sampling process?

Comment: @dkaeae: thanks for your response. Not exactly. However, this is not the focus of my question. My focus is to terminate the sampling process once the ordering of nodes is stable (will not change notably). So how to determine whether the ordering is stable or converges?

Comment: @dkaeae: please allow me to provide more information about the question. But I do not think that this information is needed to solve my question. The sampling technique is the random walk on graph and the statistics to be computed is the number of a given motif which contains the node. Simply speaking, the statistics of each node is the count of a given motif which contains this node.

Comment: @dkaeae: however, I am not interested in the exact statistics of each node. I just want the correct ordering of these nodes based on the statistics. Thus, I want to terminate the resource-consuming random walk once the ordering of nodes is stable. So what metrics/measures I can use to estimate the stability of the ordering.

Comment: Seems to be related to [sorting with noisy information](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0910.1191.pdf). See also the many follow-up papers to this work.